# Entity Framework, How to include related entities in this example

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have a table AccountSecurity which is a many-to-many table that relates Account entities and Securities.  When I write the query below it returns all Securities that satisfy the where clause.  However each Security instance in the list no longer has the reference to the AccountSecurity it came from.  So when I do list[0].AccountSecurity it is empty.  Is there anyway to include that information?  I know I can rewrite the query to return AccountSecurities instead and use .Include("Security") on that, but I wonder if it can be done another way.

```
var list = (from acctSec in base.context.AccountSecurities
            where acctSec.AccountId == accountId
            select acctSec.Security).ToList();
```

**UPDATE**

Of course if I do two queries the graph gets populated properly, there has to be a way to do this in one shot.

```
var securities = (from acctSec in base.context.AccountSecurities
            where acctSec.AccountId == accountId
            select acctSec.Security).ToList();

//this query populates the AccountSecurities references within Security instances returned by query above
var xref = (from acctSec in base.context.AccountSecurities
            where acctSec.AccountId == accountId
            select acctSec).ToList();
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var list = (from sec in base.context.Securities
                                    .Include("AccountSecurity")
            where sec.AccountSecurities.Any(as => as.AccountId == accountId)
            select sec).ToList();
```

Comment: AccountSecurity is a many-to-many table.  This means that there is only sec.AccountSecurities because a single security can belong to many accounts.  I tried doing sec.AccountSecurities[0].AccountId == accountId but that throws an exception.

Comment: thank you!  I ran this through and the only issue that I see with this is that it the securities being returned will have all a reference to all accounts they belong to, not just the one specified by accountId.  In other words if I have 5 securities, but those 5 securities are mapped to 2000 accounts then I have 5x2000 rows returned.  I think it might just be more efficient to do two queries to populate the graph with the securities first, then the acccountsecurity (many-to-many) information later.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
var list = (from acctSec in base.context.AccountSecurities.Include("Security")
            where acctSec.AccountId == accountId
            select acctSec).ToList();
```

Then simply use the Security property as needed, and since it's read at the same time AccountSecurities is (single SQL with join), it will be very efficient.

Comment: this will return a list of AccountSecurity entities and not Security entities.  I know I can easily pull them via AccountSecurity.Security but I have another issue at play here.  I don't actually go ToList() right away as I've described earlier.  I run them through a method that I wrote to dynamically sort/page these results.  Long story short I need the top level entities that are returned to be of type Security.

Comment: Then unless you also select the original AccountSecurity object at the same time, you will lose the link back to it.  eg. ... select new {Acct = acctSec, Sec = acctSec.Security} ... . Alternatively, why not use Linq to do the sorting/paging for you?  eg. Skip and Take methods?  That way it allows you freedom to select anything you want, sort it, the do the paging.  All in one scary (long) line of linq goodness.

Comment: I do use Linq to sort.  However it's a "dynamic" method I wrote that takes a string as the sort expression which represents a property of the top level entity by which to sort, a sort direction, and IQueriable.  This method will not work unless the top level (root) entity in that IQueriable matches to the sort expression.  If I were to pass to it AccountSecurity as the root and SecurityName as the sort expression it will blow up.  So you see I am in a pickle here :)  It might just be that I have to do this in two queries as I posted in my UPDATE note in the main post.